# SQL how to check whether a variable contrains non-integer character and remov the non-integer character

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to check whether variable 'prodno' contains any non-integer character.
If it does, then remove the non-integer character.

```
-- Expected output:

prodno A18
prodno K67


drop table ass3_product cascade constraints;
create table ass3_product (
prodno varchar2(30) primary key,
prodname varchar2(30),
purchasecost number(6,2)
);
insert into ass3_product values ('23','Prod One', 10);
insert into ass3_product values ('54','Prod Two', 50);
insert into ass3_product values ('A18','Prod Three', 35);
insert into ass3_product values ('9','Prod Four', 4);
insert into ass3_product values ('K67','Prod Five', 15);

SELECT prodno
FROM ass3_product
WHERE prodno like '%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%';
```

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE` does not support ranges as you seem to think - it only supports wildcard search using `%` and `_`. You need to use regular expressions for this

To remove the non-integer value use `regexp_replace`:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(prodno, '\D', '')
FROM ass3_product
```

To also test for this condition, you could compare the result of the replace with the original value:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(prodno, '\D', '')
FROM ass3_product
WHERE prodno <> regexp_replace(prodno, '\D', '');
```

Another possibility would be to use regexp_like. The following will select all rows where prodno does not start with a digit:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(prodno, '\D', '')
FROM ass3_product
where regexp_like(prodno, '^[^0-9]+')
```